# Function at the end list when printed on VF page using Remoting

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

I am using Visualforce Remoting method to display list of records on VF page.

```
htmlTable += '<tbody>';
                for(var inds in result){
                    if(inds === 'Locations'){
                        htmlTable += '<tr>';
                        htmlTable += '<td><div class="slds-truncate" title="">' + inds + '</div></td>';
                        var innerList = result[inds];

                        for(var insList in innerList){
                           if(insList != innerList.length -1){ 
                               htmlTable += '<td>'; 
                               htmlTable += '<div class="slds-truncate" title="'+ innerList[insList] +'" id="'+innerList[insList] +'">' +innerList[insList] + '</div>';
                               htmlTable += '</td>';
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
                htmlTable += '</tr>';
```

The list print wonderfully on VF page. But at the end of I also a function getting printed. Not sure why.

[image: Function printed shown in image]

Looks strange. any reason why .. ?

Comment: In the future, I recommend you spend some time doing at least some basic research before posting here. This question does not demonstrate any research effort, and in fact simply searching google for `javascript loop through array` or even just `javascript loop` would have been all you needed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic Javascript looping syntax. Use index looping instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < innerList.length; i++) {
    var innerElement = innerList[i];
    // use innerElement
}
```

If you want to use `for`/`in`, you have to check if your loop variable is actually an own property:

```
for (var property in innerList) {
    if (innerList.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var innerElement = innerList[property];
        // use innerElement
    }
}
```

See also: [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/1492485)